# shell script for remote connection to other system and execute bunch of command in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I need a shell script that can take remote login in to a system and i can execute a bunch of commands in that system.

I made a script and actually it's working:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=KRUNAL
IP=10.61.162.241
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${IP} "pwd "
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${IP} "ls -la"
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${IP} ./a.out
```

I have problem that if suppose i made script

```
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${IP} "pwd " # this execute in remote system
ls -la # this execute in current system.
```

so every time i need ssh command to execute file on remote system.
Is there any way that i can run bunch of code in remote system with one time login.

Answer (score 1):

You can send as much commands to `ssh` as you want, provided that you separate them with `;` or linebreaks. So this should work:

```
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${IP} "pwd; ls -la"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joao's suggestion works fine however its impractical when writing many lines.

If this is the case you can  do

```
ssh -1  ${USERNAME} ${IP} bash << 'EOF'
   cd /some/directory
   ./a.out
   who am i
   for i in `seq 1 10`
   do
      echo $i
   done
EOF
```

Anything between 'EOF' and the final EOF will be executed in the server side.
You can also replace `bash` with `csh` or `python` and write code for that interpreter instead

If you want the output of the ssh session be stored in a file (say session.log) then replace

```
ssh -1  ${USERNAME} ${IP} bash << 'EOF'
```

with

```
ssh -1  ${USERNAME} ${IP} bash << 'EOF' > 'session.log'
```

rest remains unchanged

Comment: what if i want to execute ./a.out in remote system and i will see the all printf statement running in that running in my current system (If possible it make a new terminal and a.out execute in it) . just like i want to xterm in remote system.

Comment: No problem!
I've updated the answer let me if that helps

Comment: yes, nice suggestion i'll work on it . Mainly my concerned to run the ./a.out file and i have to check  that my application when crashed . If it crashed than i will get alert or any information that this /.a.out stopped working .All this things done in remote system and i want to maintain from my system ..
So do you have any better idea ?? thank you

Comment: Is there any alternative for execution xterm -e ./a.out in remote system ??

Comment: You want to start GUI application on remote server? Its not that simple I am afraid. Google ssh x11 . there are many alternatives to xterm you can google that as well.
You can also also do `./a.out &> my_program_output.log` and then later you can open the file `my_program_output.log` to view the output